# C# Check all items except the first one in all listview groups

Tags: c#, listview

Having a problem trying to check all the items in a group except the first one, I'm using the following code below, what it actually does is just check all the items in the listview except the first item.

```
    foreach (ListViewGroup grp in listFiles.Groups)
    {
        foreach (ListViewItem item in grp.Items)
        {
            if (item.Index != 0)
            {
                item.Checked = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Sorry if the question is a bit confusing:
here is what it does:

[image]

What i want it to do:

[image]

Thanks for any input.

Comment: And what is the question ????

Comment: Sorry, question updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
int i;
foreach (ListViewGroup grp in listFiles.Groups)
{
   i = 0;
   foreach (ListViewItem item in grp.Items)
   {
      if (i != 0)
         item.Checked = true;

      i++;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Dont use Index property,

```
foreach (ListViewGroup grp in listFiles.Groups)
    {
      bool FirstItem = false;
        foreach (ListViewItem item in grp.Items)
        {
            if (!FirstItem)
            {
                item.Checked = false;
                FirstItem = true;
            }
            else
            {
                item.Checked = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (ListViewGroup grp in listFiles.Groups)
{
    int i = 0;
    foreach (ListViewItem item in grp.Items)
    {
        if (i != 0)
        {
            item.Checked = true;
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The question is already answered, but here is another alternative:

```
foreach (ListViewGroup grp in listFiles.Groups)
{
    foreach (var item in grp.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>().Skip(1))
    {
        item.Checked = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that works too, except that unchecks the second item instead of the first.

Comment: Humm... it works for me. I'm not sure how it can uncheck the 2nd.

Comment: I've tried it, it skips the first one. which it kinda makes sense since it starts at 0.